# German phrase that expresses a perpetual feeling of “Fernweh”

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

I am creating a typographic design piece and I speak only a little German but I want the piece to be in German. I love the idea of Fernweh and wanted to say something like

> für immer Fernweh

but I’m not sure whether that makes complete sense. I just need a short saying that expresses always having the feeling of Fernweh.

Comment: I think, as soon as someone leaves their home town/region (German: Heimat), their feeling of Fernweh is satisfied. So "immer Fernweh" sounds really negative and frustrating for me, as if someone is forced to stay at their home town.

Comment: that makes sense though, the word kind of implies the NEED to leave, as if to imply you can't stand where you are. But in english, and how we have been taught to understand the word, we see it as this idea that you always feel the need to travel, like you're always missing a place you have never been. The word wanderlust doesn't quite describe it well enough. it isn't simply just a yearning to see the world it is an absolute need. it doesn't really reflect on where you are at the moment. it is more speaking on where you want to be.

Comment: _der Moment geht, das Fernweh bleibt_

Comment: @Iris While it doesn't sound really negative to me, I agree that to some level it transports the feeling of restlessness or unsteadyness. The long version would be *Wherever I am, I always have Fernweh*, so when I'm there I want to leave again.

Answer (score 3):

*Für immer Fernweh* - isn't bad and could go as an advertising slogan (I understand that is what you are looking for). It's not what we would call a sentence, but that was not what was asked for here, I think.

*Fernweh - für immer* or *Immer Fernweh* would sort of transport the same message. The term *Fernweh* as such already has the long-going desire somewhat implied, so you could even just have it stand alone.

Comment: good! that is really all i wanted, with typography the goal isnt to form a sentence but more of a bit of words to convey an idea all while making it so aesthetically beautiful it becomes artwork. like poetry and graphic design came together basically hah

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

> chronisches Fernweh

*Chronisch* comes from the medical sector, where it describes a sickness having grown permanent, which seems appropriate here. *Dauernd* would be an alternative to *chronisch*.

Another idea would be, to use *Reiselust* (desire to travel) instead of *Fernweh*

Answer (score 1):

You could also say

> Ständig Fernweh

*Ständig* means *all the time/constantly*.

Answer (score 1):

What about "Der Ruf der Ferne"? (like "call of the wild", could be translated back something like "I feel the call of foreign countries", just leaving out "I feel")

Answer (score 0):

You can say "Ich habe für immer Fernweh". But that kinda implies that you left a certain country that you started to love and you imply that you are 100% sure that you will never get back there.

A softer approach would be "Ich habe immer Fernweh", which doesn't imply anything about the future and is more of a statement that you currently have permanent Fernweh.

Comment: Hang on, what you are describing is what I would rather translate as "Heimweh", the exact opposite of "Fernweh". "Fernweh" is being bound to a single place (be it because of the job, family, poverty), but really longing to be able to explore foreign lands and countries.

Comment: Ah, I think you are right. His "Für immer Fernweh" just sounded to me like a reverse Heimweh. Like in: Ich musste Deutschland jetzt verlassen und wieder nach Amerika ziehen. Ich glaube ich habe nun für immer Fernweh.